# a good way to fill my form, after getting json data

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

i'm working on a small project using VueJs, so i fetch the **Mysql** data using **axios**. and i'm going to make the edit option, to edit user profile, i would like to know the better way to fill the form after getting mysql data in json.
my question  is : 
what is the best way to fill the form after getting json data. i'm looking for something as **vform** plugin. or any good way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn’t need a plug-in.

In VueJS, you can bind data to a form element using v-model.

So let’s say you have an object:

```
view: {
    foo: ‘bar’
}
```

You can use this ...

```
<input type=“text” v-model=“view.foo” />
```

In this case, when foo is set by your axios callback, the text box will automatically update its value. And likewise, when you change the text in the input, your object will update. This is called two-way binding.